# How to prevent react native picker firing onvaluechange when prop change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-native

I have a picker to select some items. These items includes pending items which is basically waiting for internet to come back on and sync with server. Lets assume the list is:

```
[ {id:'1', name:'one'},
  {id:'2', name:'two'},
  {id:'local_3', name:'three'} ]
```

Here `local_3` is a item that was created offline and waiting to be synced when the devices goes online.

When I have `three` selected on the picker the `selectedValue={state.chosenValue}` where chosenValue holds `local_3` and then i turn on the internet and it syncs and the redux state (basically `{id:'local_3', name:'three'}` becomes `{id:'3', name:'three'}`) updates and the value which was set on `selectedValue` also updates. And just that moment `onValueChange` fires with the first item (one in this case) and since I have a code to set items to the set with that function it sets the first item to the state value of `chosenValue`

How would I handle it so that when I select the pending one and it gets updated and the picker still keeps this value selected(the new id in this case) ?

Comment: Can you change the shape of your object? Instead of changing the id, keep it the same, but use a flag `local: true` which could eventually be deleted after sync.

Comment: @ChrisR I cant because the id is coming from server after sync and the whole project follows this structure :(